# clone fails with "smudge filter lfs failed (...) HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED"

Tags: azure-devops, git-lfs

I'm trying to clone a git repo from my corp locally-hosted TFS/devops. However, I get failure:
`batch response: Post (...) HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED`

I saw recommendation to skip smudge by running `git lfs install --skip-smudge`
or setting `GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1`, but then the lfs-provided binaries don't get pulled and I get compile errors.

Answer (score 8):

**Solution** - Before clone, run: `git config --global --replace-all http.version HTTP/1.1`

Ref, from the git-lfs developer which added the http.version option: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3875#issuecomment-607260728